AccountEnabled user property from Azure AD returning null
I am trying to get a group of users from azure ad graph. When I make the call it is returning the AccountEnabled property as null. After doing some research I noticed that it is most likely related to api permissions assingned to the app registration I am using for the token. I added the User.Read.All permission to it which should add the correct permissions to read all properties of a user but I am still getting null for AccountEnabled. I am building the token using the app registration credentials. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
        public async Task<List<GroupMember>> GetAllGroupMembers(string userAccessToken, string destination)
    {
        var centreDetails = await _centreService.GetCentreDetailsBy(userAccessToken, destination);
        var graphClient = await GetGraphClient();
        var groupMembers = new List<GroupMember>();

        var transitiveMembers = await graphClient.Groups[centreDetails.distributionGroup.azureId].TransitiveMembers.Request().GetAsync();
        while (transitiveMembers != null && transitiveMembers.Count > 0)
        {
            var members = transitiveMembers.CurrentPage.Where(member => member is User);
            foreach (User member in members)
            {
                groupMembers.Add(new GroupMember
                {
                    Id = member.Id,
                    Name = member.DisplayName,
                    AccountEnabled = member.AccountEnabled
                });
            }
            if (transitiveMembers.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                transitiveMembers = await transitiveMembers.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return groupMembers;
    }


By default graph doesn't return this property. Instead you have to explicitly select which properties you need. Due to the used syntax you're running the Graph v4 SDK and not the current v5 SDK. I currently don't remember anymore on how to specify the desired properties in v4 (maybe specifying the parameter in the .Request() method?).

In v4 SDK you define the desired properties by calling .Request().Select("id,displayName,accountEnabled").GetAsync();

Thanks for this! It is working with the "Select" I assumed that since I wasn't selecting the values for displayName and Id that it wasn't required and was more related to token permissions.

If you don't select anything you will get back a standard set. If you need something specific you have to explicitly declare all desired properties. If you send a call by using the graph explorer you'll get back a tip in the response.

Hi @Oliver If it is OK I think you can move your comment to the answer section so we can mark as accepted and allow anyone else with the same issue to easily spot and solve it.

By default graph doesn't return this property and you will get back a standard set. If you need something specific you have to explicitly declare all desired properties. If you send a call by using the graph explorer you'll get back this as a tip in the response.
Instead you have to explicitly select which properties you need and in v4 SDK you define the desired properties by calling .Request().Select("id,displayName,accountEnabled").GetAsync();
